# Dynamically hidden list items in _Layout nav bar not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using MVC5, I am dynamically setting the style to hide and show menu items in the _Layout nav bar. The DOM elements update correctly when I inspect the html after the URL helper sets the style, but the browser doesn't show the menu items. I'm using URL helper extension to set my style property (tried setting the class as well) like below:

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Index", "Schedule")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index", "Contact", new { CompanyId = ViewBag.CompanyId }, htmlAttributes: new {  })</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Tools</a>
                    <ul id="toolsMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        @{ 
                            var menuItemStyle = Url.MenuItemStyle(User.Identity.GetUserName());
                        }
                        <li style=@menuItemStyle ><a href="#">Tool1</a></li>
                        <li style=@menuItemStyle ><a href="#">Tool2</a></li>
                        <li style=@menuItemStyle ><a href="#">Tool3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
```

The extension method looks like this:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string MenuItemStyle(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string username)
    {
        string result = "";

        int userType = GetUserType(username);

       if ( userType < 2)
        {
            result = "display:none";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I've also tried using a partial view to build dynamic menu items, again it builds the correct DOM elements but when viewing this in I.E. or Chrome, the menu drop down items do not show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the before screenshot of the DOM that hides the menu item correctly.
[image]

Here is the after picture that sets the correct style but now the menu item doesn't function.
[image]

Tried changing the extension method to create the list items only when the user type is greater than 1. Still have the same problem. The DOM is generated correctly every time but the browser does not render what's in the DOM?

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Tools</a>
                    <ul id="toolsMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        @{ 
                            var menuItems = Url.GetMenuItems(User.Identity.GetUserName());
                        }
                        @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in menuItems)
                        {
                            <li><a href="#">@kvp.Key</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

After testing posting back the user type from the extension method and not setting any style on the elements, i'm seeing that the drop down toggle is not working. This seems to me that the drop down toggle is not working after getting post back from the extension method.

Comment: Why do you have an extension method for this (its not necessary at all and the code does not even use the `UrlHelper`). Are you saying all your `<li>` elements are rendered with `style="display:none"`? And why are you generating the `<li>` elements anyway if you want then to be hidden? This can be simply done in an `if` block

Comment: They are conditional for a reason, they are hidden so they exist and can be bound to without seeing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out that the boot strap class of toggle drop down wasn't working after post back, i look further into that issue. Turns out that the page I redirected to after login, is registering the boot strap bundle, this bundle was already being registered at the layout level so it did not need to be registered again, this was causing the boot strap menu behavior to fail on this page regardless if any items on the menu were hidden or shown. I also took Stephen Muecke's advice and now I only create the list items needed, using the extension method instead of showing or hiding items.

EDIT: Adding code that now extends IIdentity.

```
                <ul id="toolsMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    @{ 
                        var menuItems = User.Identity.GetUserMenuItems();
                    }
                    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in menuItems)
                    {
                        <li id=@kvp.Key><a href="#">@kvp.Value</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
```

Again the solution was removing the extra...

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

on the page that the user was re-directed to after login.

Comment: The extension item makes no sense - it in no way relates the the `UrlHelper` class (it related to css styles. Just create a static method - `public static string MenuItemStyle(string username){ ... }` in another class

Comment: You're right UrlHelper has nothing to do with this. I've made the method extend IIdentity.

Answer (score -1):

Your li elements do not show up because you possibly always set the style to `style="display:none"`
Check what happens if your userType is >=2

Based on your html code it should work. Here is a basic example with html and jquery only.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    <input type="button" id="toggleList" value="toggle" />

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Tools</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Tool1</a></li>
                <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Tool2</a></li>
                <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Tool3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#toggleList').on('click', function (event) {
        $('li').removeAttr('style');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I can manually set the style in the extension just to turn the display on or of, but the point is toggling using the extension sets the correct style, and if you look at the source code in the browser the DOM elements are built correctly, however the browser is acting like it doesn't know the DOM elements have changed. I will however try to toggle in reverse.

Comment: How do you expect them to change? You set the display based on the username. They are either showing for a userType or not.

Comment: I lookup the type based on user name.